# Webpack cannot get react components but home page

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I'm new to webpack so I'm trying to use it with my react express app. I created a bundle and upload it to hosting but it opens only the home page and when I try to use links to reach other pages I get "Cannot GET /about", for example. And webpack-dev-server acts the same. Is there a plugin that I have to use?

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./client/public/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html",
    favicon: "./client/public/favicon.ico"
})

module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [
        htmlPlugin
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    query: {
                        presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router or routing in react with any other package, you need to make sure that your server redirects all routes to your home page so that react can mange routing.